# Dynamically select source for document list

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

I've got a webpart page where the user selects a company. This is the provider webpart for other webparts.

At the bottom the page my customer wants a list of documents related to the selected company. Each company got its own document library, so I need to somehow set the document library for the document list.

How can this be done? Will I have to create my own webpart with a SPGridView from scratch, or can I set the source for the document list dynamically (based on the filtervalue from the search webpart)? Or....?

Thanks

Ivar

Comment: Found this page: http://www.sharepointkings.com/2008/08/create-custom-listviewwebpart.html It solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own web part of course. But why not use a single doc lib for all customers and filter by a customer column?

Comment: Sorry for answering late, but there was some concerns about that the doc lib would be too large for SP2007. After what I've heard now there might not be an issue. Not in Sharepoint 2010 at least